# Can't see changes in file on remote Unix machine "on fly"

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, auto-revert-mode

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

in my .emacs I have:

```
(global-auto-revert-mode t)
```

So when I open file (in dired mode)  on my LOCAL machine it's success refresh opened file "**on fly**".
Nice.

Now I want to do same on file on remote machine.
I success connect to remote Unix machine by **Tramp** mode:

```
/mylogin@111.222.333.444:
```

Open file (in dired mode).
But when file change it's not refresh "**on fly**". I need to close file and reopen again to see changes.

How I can see "**on fly**" changes in file on remote Unix machine.

Comment: Please note that the upcoming Emacs 26.1 will require a method in the remote file name. Something like `/ssh:mylogin@111.222.333.444:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set `auto-revert-remote-files` to a non-nil value.